# MYSQL API in C - linux

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-error-1064

I can't get the following code to work. It's working with normal select or insert, but when I try to insert a variable to it it didn't work. Can some let me know please what's wrong here?

Please note that the output is below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  MYSQL *conn;
  char str[100] = "test";
  conn = mysql_init(NULL);

  char stmt_buf[100];
  sprintf (stmt_buf, "insert into test values ('%s')", str);

  printf("\n%s\n",stmt_buf);

  mysql_query (conn, stmt_buf);
  mysql_close(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

`~$./version`

```
insert into test values ('test')
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You should run your program through GDB to find out where it's crashing. `gdb ./version` -> `run`

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`), to improve your code till no warnings are given by the compiler, and to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`)??

Comment: I did but the output wasn't helpful as below.                   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00199634 in mysql_send_query () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16

Comment: I always use -Wall -g and there was no error

Comment: **"it didn't work" is _not_ an error description.**

Comment: -1: If you'd done any debugging whatsoever, you'd see that `conn` is `0x0`.

Comment: @BagDev check my answer which has an example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit anyone who can debug should not have such basic mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see you are connected to database by [`mysql_real_connect`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html)
also there is no [`mysql_select_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-select-db.html) and [`mysql_exec_sql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-exec-sql.html) call.

Here is an example for you.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MYSQL mysql;
    char stmt_buf[100];
    if (mysql_init(&mysql) == NULL) {
        printf("Can not initialize");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!mysql_real_connect
        (&mysql, "localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", NULL, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        mysql_error(&mysql);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_select_db(&mysql, "DATABASENAME")) {
        mysql_error(&mysql);
        exit(1);
    }

    sprintf(stmt_buf, "insert into test values ('%s')", "test");

    if (mysql_exec_sql(&mysql, stmt_buf))
        mysql_error(&mysql));

    mysql_close(&mysql);
}
```

Comment: Please note: this is a SQL injection waiting to happen if someone replaces "test" with untrusted user input. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

You don't do any error checking.  My guess is `conn == NULL`.

For the record, don't use `sprintf` ever.  Use `snprintf` instead, that is, if you're okay with SQL injections.